# How to compare generic types based on constraints

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, type-inference

Assume that I have two classes, Foo and Bar.

```
public class Foo<TFirst, TSecond, TThird, T> 
       where TFirst : IReadOnlyList<T>
       where TThird : IEnumerable<T>
{
}

public class Bar<TFirst, TSecond, TThird, T> 
       where TFirst : IReadOnlyList<T>
{
}
```

Now I want to compare their generic types. I'm using equality comparer to operate on array of types. like Intersect, Subtract etc.

I don't want to compare `Foo` and `Bar` but I want to compare their Generic parameters.

for example if both type parameters have same constraint, they should be considered equal. if they have no constrained they should be considered equal too.

In above example `TFirst` of Foo should be considered equal to `TFirst` of Bar. as well as `TSecond` because they have no constraint. `TThrid`s are not equal because they don't have same constraint.

So now I have Foo and Bar types. I want to analyze their type arguments and compare them against each other.

```
var fooType = typeof(Foo<,,,>);
var barType = typeof(Bar<,,,>);

var fooArgs = fooType.GetGenericArguments();
var barArgs = barType.GetGenericArguments();

var commonArgs = fooArgs.Intersect(barArgs, new GenericArgumentEqualityComparer()).ToArray();

var unknownBarArgs = barArgs.Except(commonArgs, new GenericArgumentEqualityComparer()).ToArray();
```

Following Equality comparer always returns false, no matter I use `IsAssignableFrom` or `==`. what is the right way to do this?

```
public class GenericArgumentEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Type>
{
    public bool Equals(Type x, Type y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null) return false;
        var xcons = x.GetGenericParameterConstraints();
        var ycons = y.GetGenericParameterConstraints();

        if(xcons.Length != ycons.Length) return false;

        foreach (var cons in xcons)
        {
            if (ycons.All(cons2 => !cons.IsAssignableFrom(cons2)))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Type obj)
    {
        // code runs on T4 for code generation. performance doesn't matter.
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: your code will not compile  as T is not defined. Did you mean TSecond

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel you can add another type parameter `T`. sorry I missed that. they are just examples though

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel the point is, since `T` has no constraint, it should be considered equal whether taken from Foo or Bar. if constraints are defined, they must be same in order to be considered equal.

Answer (score 0):

the unexpected behavior comes from the

```
cons.IsAssignableFrom
```

you cannot try to assign open generic type from derived to base even if hierarchically possible 
take this as an example

```
var ien = typeof(IEnumerable<string>);
            var iread = typeof(IReadOnlyList<string>);
            //isAssignable will be true 
            var isAssignable = ien.IsAssignableFrom(iread);
            //here because IsAssignableFrom work from BaseType.IsAssignableFrom(DerviedType)       
            var isAssignableIEn = iread.IsAssignableFrom(ien);
```

and this One

```
var ien = typeof(IEnumerable<>);
            var iread = typeof(IReadOnlyList<>);
            var isAssignable = ien.IsAssignableFrom(iread);
            //here because IsAssignableFrom work from BaseType.IsAssignableFrom(DerviedType)       
            var isAssignableIEn = iread.IsAssignableFrom(ien);
```

both of the assignment checks will  be `false` this is an expected behavior because an open generic type cannot be instantiated by default so is not assignable

to create an instance of open generic type you should use [`Type.MakeGenericType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype(v=vs.110).aspx)

To resolve your issue this may help you

```
public class GenericArgumentEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Type>
    {
        public bool Equals(Type x, Type y)
        {

            var xInterfacesTypes = x.GetInterfaces();
            var yInterfacesTypes = y.GetInterfaces();
            if (!xInterfacesTypes.Any()&&!yInterfacesTypes.Any() )
            {
                return true; 
            }
            if ((!xInterfacesTypes.Any() && yInterfacesTypes.Any()) || xInterfacesTypes.Any() && !yInterfacesTypes.Any())
            {
                return false; 
            }          
            foreach (var xInterfacesType in xInterfacesTypes)
            {
                var iType = xInterfacesType.IsGenericType ? xInterfacesType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() :xInterfacesType;
                var yType = yInterfacesTypes.Any(yI => yI.IsGenericType && yI.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == iType||yI.GetType()==xInterfacesType.GetType());
                if (!yType)
                {
                    return false;
                }

            }
            return true; 
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Type obj)
        {
            return obj.Name.GetHashCode(); 
        }
    }
```